# vim - how to find lines with specified amount of specified characters

Tags: vim

I have 100k lines file and some lines has unescaped apostrophe, like:

```
""Luis" number 4"
```

I want:

```
"\"Luis\" number 4"
```

so how can I find all lines having more than 2 `"` character. is it possible to do it easly in vim ? otherwise it is for simple script task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to find such lines you can search as follows:

```
/.*".*".*".*
```

where `.*` will match zero or more characters and `"` is the literal quote you're looking for.

The first and last `.*` patterns aren't strictly necessary, but they make sure the whole line is highlighted when a search is found.

Comment: This regex is already mentioned in my answer which will do the find and replace in the OP's question. It should be obvious enough that the "find" part works independently.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Your version of the regex has four quotes and includes parentheses that are only needed because of the substitution, so it's not the same. I'm simply answering the question as asked.

Comment: OK, I can drop the outer `.*` from yours since regexes already match in the middle of words. Should I post this as another separate answer?

Comment: The final `.*` isn't strictly necessary, but does make sure the whole line is highlighted when a search is found (i.e. it was deliberate). I've updated my answer to make that point.

Comment: You could make the same comment about the first `.*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
:%s/""\([^"]*\)"\(.*\)"/"\\"\1\\"\2"/
```

Comment: If you're answering with one-liner, at least explain what it does.

Comment: the answer is pretty understood, but not what I want - I need find lines, do not want any auto-replaces in file.
But what I need is above command + 'c' like confirm each substitution.

Answer (score 0):

```
%s/\v"(.*)"(.*)"(.*)"/"\1\\"\2\\"\3"/
```

Breaking this down:

- `%s`: Substitute on every line
- `\v`: Very magic (don't have to escape all those parens in regex)
- `"(.*)"(.*)"(.*)"`: Anything in quotes anywhere inside anything in quotes

And replace with a quote, everything up to the opening inner quote (`\1`), an escaped quote, everything inside the inner quotes (`\2`), another escaped quote, then the rest (`\3`) and a close quote.